# Perform a successive XOR along rows

Tags: matlab, xor

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a successive XOR on a row in matlab, where each element is the result of XORing itself and the previous element, for example:

If the row is

```
x = [1 0 1 1]
```

I would want the result to be:

```
x[0] = 1
x[1] = x[0]^x[1] = 1
x[2] = x[1]^x[2] = 0
x[3] = x[2]^x[3] = 1
x = [1 1 0 1]
```

I have tried using xor(A,B) but this only seems to work on multiple arrays at once. I also have tried this loop:

```
for k = 10000:1
    for i = 1:64
        allchallenge_full(k,i+1) = xor(allchallenge_full(k,i).^allchallenge_full(k,i+1))
    end
end
```

But this simply results in all 1s.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep things simple, a `for` loop, together with the [xor function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html) (`^` in Matlab represents the raising to a power), should work fine:

```
x = [1 0 1 1];

for i = 2:numel(x)
    x(i) = xor(x(i-1),x(i));
end
```

The final output is the expected one:

```
x =
     1     1     0     1
```

Remember that, in Matlab, indexing is one-based and not zero-based as in many other programming languages. The first element of `x` is, therefore, `x(1)` and not `x(0)`.

Comment: You could also vectorize this easily: `y = [x(1) xor(x(1:(end-1)), x(2:end))];`

Comment: Nope... it's about successive xors.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

If the input `x` is just zeros and ones:

```
result = mod(cumsum(x), 2);
```

To apply it on each row of a matrix `x`:

```
result = mod(cumsum(x,2), 2);
```